# Android - What API can I use to see if a device supports BLE central mode?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#roles

> Central vs. peripheral. This applies to the BLE connection itself. The
>   device in the central role scans, looking for advertisement, and the
>   device in the peripheral role makes the advertisement.

To check if a device supports "peripheral"/advertisement mode it looks as though I can use getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()

> getBluetoothLeAdvertiser
>
> added in API level 21 public
>
> BluetoothLeAdvertiser getBluetoothLeAdvertiser () Returns a
>   BluetoothLeAdvertiser object for Bluetooth LE Advertising operations.
>   Will return null if Bluetooth is turned off or if Bluetooth LE
>   Advertising is not supported on this device.
>
> Use isMultipleAdvertisementSupported() to check whether LE Advertising
>   is supported on this device before calling this method.

Now I've heard some rumors that some devices can actually give you a BluetoothLeAdvertiser, but return false on `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` which is another issue in itself, but on the central side of things, the docs don't say **anything!**

Am I missing something? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter doesn't say anything about central mode. Am I missing something basic here? Thanks for any help. I have heard bluetooth is a pain on Android and it is my first day exploring these APIs.

Comment: Your phone is almost always the Central role, i.e. it's the device that is scanning, looking for peripherals. When you say "see if a device supports BLE central mode", are you referring to the phone or some other device? Because if you're talking about a phone then it most certainly supports BLE central mode because any phone made in the last 4-5 years (maybe more) will have a Bluetooth chipset that supports BLE

Comment: this might help you to understand the ble correctly https://www.mikroe.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-part-1-introduction-ble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer**

As DigitalNinja pointed out, an Android phone will always support Central role functionality by default, so if your phone supports BLE, then it can definitely operate in the central Role

**Long Answer**

You're right, the API might not be straight-forward but this is down to how Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) API was added to Android and even down to the history of BLE technology itself.

When BLE was first introduced, it was aimed to be for sensors only (e.g. thermometer, heart rate, proximity, etc) and devices that talk to these sensors. The sensors were the **peripherals** in this case, and the devices that talk to these sensors are the **centrals**. The peripherals were the true Low Energy (LE) devices, as they would just advertise and send data once in a while. Centrals on the other hand would not be very power efficient as they would have to continuously scan for devices, connect to these devices, and remain in charge of maintaining and monitoring that connection, meaning the radio would be on for a much longer time when compared to the peripheral.

When Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) API was added to Android, it supported Central role only. In other words, you could write an Android app to scan and connect to peripherals (sensors), but the Android device itself could not act as a peripheral (Because the assumption was that you wouldn't need an Android device to act as a sensor). This was done in [Android 4.3 (API 18)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le).

As people started to use BLE more often and the technology matured, it started being used for all sorts of different applications (e.g. virtual serial port, data transfer, beacons, etc). Moreover, standalone central devices started appearing in the market and there was a need to use them with phones or at least test them out against phones/tablets during the development stages. As such, the distinction between central and peripheral started becoming fuzzier and fuzzier, and there was a demand for Android to start supporting peripheral role. This is when the BLE API was updated to introduce peripheral role functionality, which happened in [Android 5.0 (API 21)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0).

So to answer your question, if BLE is supported on an Android device then it is safe to state that it will by default support central role as this is the foundation of the BLE functionality for Android. However, API was introduced later to support the peripheral role, which is why not all Android devices that support BLE will support peripheral role.

Finally, please note that isMultipleAdvertisementSupported is a different feature which indicates if your device supports sending out multiple adverts at the same time. Some devices support sending out different adverts simultaneously, while others don't. However, this does not mean that they do not support advertising at all. A device that supports `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported` will definitely support `BluetoothLeAdvertiser`, but the other way around is not guaranteed.

To conclude, the safest way to check if your device supports central and/or peripheral role is through the Android version and the API level used, as indicated by the two links above. On Android 5 (API 21) onwards, you can write applications that support both central and peripheral roles, whereas before that you can only write applications for the central role.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It looks like if getBLEScanner returns a valid object, that means the device is capable of central mode, and if getBLEAdvertiser returns a valid object, that means the device is capable of being in peripheral mode.