# How to check, which mode type being used by the bluetooth device Central or peripheral Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application which retrieve the information about Bluetooth device of the android application. Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643073/android-what-api-can-i-use-to-see-if-a-device-supports-ble-central-mode) to know if central or peripheral mode is supported by the phone. But need to get information that which mode is device using currently?

Comment: Do you want to know which mode your own app uses or any app on your phone?

Comment: wanna know about my own app.

Comment: What stops you from keeping track of your app by yourself? Maybe you could store the current mode in a variable whenever you switch from central to peripheral or even to simultaneous central&peripheral.

Comment: can you please refer any method to obtain the current mode's value?

Comment: I don't know if such a method exists. I thought you would see whether you used a central or peripheral connection in your own code

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan thank you fro your response. I will check if I get any solution about that. Do you have any information to obtain the mode being used by bluetooth app or any other app?

Comment: Somewhere in your app, you started listening to advertisements of your BLE device. This means you are in central mode. If you started to advertise instead you are in peripheral mode. It is also possible that you're doing both simultaneously.